# php Date conditions with database datetime in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying something like this.
`delivery_pick_ups.start_time = 2018-09-06 16:30:00` and
`$params['pick_date'] = 2018-09-06`

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'and',
    ['>=', 'DATE(delivery_pick_ups.start_time)', $params['pick_date']],
    ['<=', 'DATE(delivery_pick_ups.end_time)', $params['pick_date']]
]);
```

I don't know if that is possible in yii2 yet or not.

Comment: Convert your date time variable in to the date using `strtotime` function

Comment: @prakashtank This is not working for me

Comment: What is not working? your query? clarify your question. Condition looks ok.

Comment: are you getiing any query error or the results are not accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up conditions

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'and',
    ['<=', 'DATE(delivery_pick_ups.start_time)', $params['pick_date']],
    ['>=', 'DATE(delivery_pick_ups.end_time)', $params['pick_date']]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use that you must use `yii\db\Expression`

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
   'and',
   ['>=', new \yii\db\Expression('DATE(delivery_pick_ups.start_time)'), $params['pick_date']],
   ['<=', new \yii\db\Expression('DATE(delivery_pick_ups.end_time)'), $params['pick_date']]
]);
```

Comment: Actually it is not true - second value in this array will be treated as expression anyway, so you don't need to use `yii\db\Expression` here.